# facebook register link to rules

Tags: facebook, api

Is it possible to embed a link in the field description ?

I would like a checkbox field "I accept the *rules*" and to redirect the user to the rules using a _blank link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that’s not possible.

But your apps privacy policy URL and TOS URL will be shown in the footer of the plugin (as well as in the auth dialog) – so maybe you could just alert the user to read these before checking the checkbox with simple *text* in the field description (“see link below” …) instead of having a link right next to the checkbox.